# Enter is not working in Internet explorer and Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is not working in Internet Explorer and Firefox. In Firefox, it returns the following error:

> TypeError: e is undefined
>   [Break On This Error]
>   ...e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode; keyCodeEntered = (e.which) ? e.which...

The function:

```
function onSearchPhraseKeyDown(e) {
    var buttonId = '<%=SearchButton.ClientID %>';
        if (!e)
            var e = (typeof e.which == "number") ? e.which : e.keyCode;
        keyCodeEntered = (e.which) ? e.which : window.event.keyCode;

        if ((keyCodeEntered == 13) || (keyCodeEntered == 13)) {
            document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
}
```

Can anyone see what's wrong?

Comment: What code is calling this? Can you show us a fragment of your page?

Comment: This is calling on button click of search when I press enter in firefox and internet explorer it wont work.

Comment: Yes, show me the tag where you've got onkeypress/onkeydown

Comment: Check the condition: `if (!e)...` so the loop is only entered if `e` is undefined, which is not what you want. In that case, attempting to access any property of `e` will return the error you see.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
function onSearchPhraseKeyDown(e) {
    var buttonId = '<%=SearchButton.ClientID %>';
    var e = e || event;
    var key = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if (key===13) {
        document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
        return false;
    }
}
```

If you are using `return false` to cancel the default behaviour of this event, I suggest you to use `e.preventDefault()` instead, like this:

```
if (key===13) {
    document.getElementById(buttonId).click();
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Odd... From where are you calling this function? And are you passing any parameter?

Comment: I am calling this function from code behind like this
 string handleEnterScript = String.Format("return onSearchPhraseKeyDown()");
SearchPhrase.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", handleEnterScript);
and I am not passing any parameter.

Comment: Hmm, that's why isn't working. This function I wrote is made to be called by an event like keydown. Try `myField.onkeydown = onSearchPhraseKeyDown`

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mark Linus, thank you man you done a great job save me from this headache.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE> New Document </TITLE>
<META NAME="Generator" CONTENT="EditPlus">
<META NAME="Author" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Keywords" CONTENT="">
<META NAME="Description" CONTENT="">
</HEAD>
<script>
function checkEnter(event) {
if(event && event.which && event.which == 13) {

    alert("enter pressed");
}else if(event && event.keyCode && event.keyCode == 13) {

    alert("enter pressed");

}
return true;
}
</script>
<BODY  >
<div contenteditable id="temp"  style ="height:220px;background:white;width:545px;text-align:left;overflow:auto;margin:0px;border:solid 1px #999999;font-family:Arial;font-size: 10pt;color: black;" onKeyPress="return checkEnter(event)">

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Please try this**

Comment: Not working in firefox but working perfectly in Internet explorer and chrome can you please fix it for fire fox please.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option based on what I think that you are trying to accomplish:

If you are trying to make a form postback when a user presses enter while in some input field, you can use the DefaultButton property of either the panel control or the HtmlForm. Here is an example using the HtmlForm.DefaultButton property:

**Default.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="SubmitButton">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="InputTextBox" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
        <asp:Label ID="InputValue" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.vb**

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub SubmitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SubmitButton.Click
        InputValue.Text = InputTextBox.Text
    End Sub
End Class
```

Run this example and the label will contain the value of the textbox as an easy way to prove that the postback is occuring. There are a few caveats to this approach, namely that the target of the DefaultButton property must be either a Button or ImageButton. LinkButton is not allowed. More info at the following links:

[system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.panel.defaultbutton.aspx)

[system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlform.defaultbutton.aspx)